# Custom wordpress post filter without refresh and same number of items

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post

I am working on my own recipe site. I use wordpress and created a custom post type for recipes. There are different categories like "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dessert", etc.

On my homepage I want to implement a simple filter -> see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEfZG.jpg)

Now here is the tricky part. In the beginning I want to show 16 recipes/posts (thumbnail and title) of different categories. After clicking - for example - on breakfast, there should be one more time 16 recipes of the type "Breakfast". And it should work without refreshing of the page.

The standard filters just hide not selected items.. but here it should load more items of the same categories. So there are always 16 items.

I googled a whole day to find a script. I am not the best programmer, so maybe somebody give me a link to a tutorial or something similar.

All I found out was, with ajax it is possible to reload without refresh. But how I combine wordpress, ajax and a filter javascript...

Thx in advanced!!!

P.S. a plugin wouldn't be the solution because I want to add the code in my own page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this problem. The first - and not entirely efficient way would be to load all your options at the same time and use a Jquery filter like **Isotope** - see: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/. You will have to change the markup and introduce a little bit of Javascript but you won't have to write any Ajax calls but it's a great system for filtering objects and is relatively easy to set up.

The second - and more complex option - would be to use the **Wordpress Admin Ajax** functionality which requires a little bit more knowledge of how the ajax system works in Wordpress.

It is explained here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

1. Setting up an action call in your funcions.php
2. Defining button listeners for your filter items (on click)
3. Defining a javascript handler for the on click actions that call the function you wroteand to return the data

This is also a very helpful tutorial to get started on the problem: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-primer-on-ajax-in-the-wordpress-frontend-understanding-the-process--wp-27052

Comment: isotope was a good hint. for the first run I would try it with isotope. the filter function looks nice!